# Jupyter Lab is not using virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter-lab

I created a virtual environment and installed `ipython[all]` and `jupyter` with pip. When I run `jupyter lab`, open a notebook, and try importing a package I installed inside the virtual environment, I get “ModuleNotFoundError.”

Running `ipython` in the console and importing works. Also, `which jupyter` does point me to the right executable in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from the fact that your environment is not registered in the kernelspec. You can activate your venv, run

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=some_nice_name
```

and then select the kernel some_nice_name for your notebook (you can use the kernel even if you run jupyter lab from another venv ; keep in mind that the python running jupyter lab and the kernel are in general different)

Answer (score 1):

install jupyter lab in the virtual env:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing `jupyter`, I need to install `jupyter lab`. Otherwise, even the virtual environment `jupyter` executable actually silently falls back to the system Jupyter Lab installation.